# How Do I retrieve a URL Protocol Request in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, protocols

I have a Windows WPF application running in the background at all times.  I have registered a URL protocol in with the application called WTL:.  The protocol works when the application is closed, but how do I respond to it when the application is open or running in the background?  I have clients that are using WinXP, so the new protocol handling in Win8 isn't sufficient.

I figured OnNavigated or OnActivated might work, but the protocol doesn't work with those.  Should I run something that is always listening to the protocol?  Help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK - i had to read over this two times but now i think i know what you mean. I have had a similar task, not with WPF but in WinForms... (almost the same in that case).
I don't know what "WTL" does exactly, because i registered my own protocol manually at the application startup.

You can view the current settings by opening the registry editor and goto **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT**
Beneath you can find your "protocol" (dont know yours, so for example i take "callto://") 
Browse to the command-subkey **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\callto\shell\open\command** - The default entry points to your application. The value must look like:
**"path_to_your_application.exe" "%1"** *(including the double-quotes!)*

Important is the **"%1"**

This value represents the argument for your application instance.
Reading commandline args isn't really a complicated task in .net.
But it's getting a little bit tricky, if you allow only one instance!

For me the **best approach** for a single-instance application & getting those
*"second instance-commandline-args"* can be found under:
[Codeproject: WPF Single Instance Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84270/WPF-Single-Instance-Application)

Long story short: A request to your application can look like:
**"callto://008291478624599"**
In which the number will be filled in the args for your 2nd application startup request (the %1)

Comment: Dude, you are beyond the Man.  You are awesome!  Thank you! I reviewed that code project, but didn't think it was for me, but you helped me fully understand it.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: ty! - after reading a 3rd time i saw WTL is your protocol ;) not an application ;) - but i think you got it!

Comment: @bonitzenator - tried it - still works in Windows10 - the fault must be on your side with your confguration